# Error in multiple regression: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, logistic-regression, training-data

I am trying to split my data into training and test data using a code obtained from my professor but am getting errors. I thought it was because of the data's format, but I went back to hard code it and nothing works. The data is in matrix form right now and I believe the code is being used to predict how accurate the logistic regression is.

```
A = matrix(
  c(64830,18213,4677,24761,9845,17504,22137,12531,5842,28827,66161,18852,5581,27219,10159,17527,23402,11409,8115,31425,68426,18274,5513,25687,10971,14104,19604,13438,6011,30055,69716,18366,5735,26556,11733,16605,20644,15516,5750,31116,73128,18906,5759,28555,11951,19810,22086,17425,6152,28469,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1),

nrow = 10,
ncol = 6,
byrow = FALSE)


n<-row(A);
K<-ncol(A)-1;
x<-matrix(0,n,K);

for(i in 1:K){x[,i]<-A[,i];}
#A[,i] is 10long and x[,i] is 1long.
A[,i:length(x[,i])]=x[,i]
y<-A[,K+1];
#training/test data split:
idx<-sample(1:n,floor(n/2),replace=FALSE);
xtr<-x[idx,]; ytr<-y[idx];
xts<-x[-idx,]; yts<-y[-idx];
#fit the logistic model to it
myglm<-glmnet(xtr,ytr,family = "binomial"); 
#Error in if (is.null(np) | (np[2] <= 1)) stop("x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns") : argument is of length zero

#apply traning data to test data
mypred<-predict(myglm,newx=xts,type="response",s=0.01);
posteriprob<-mypred[,,1];
yhat<-matrix(1,nrow(xts),1);
for(i in 1:nrow(xts))
{
  yhat[i]<-which.max(posteriprob[i,]);
}

acc<-sum(yhat+2==yts)/nrow(xts);
cat("accuracy of test data:", acc, "\n");
```

The first forloop gives me this error:
Error in `x[, i] <- A[, i]`:

> Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

When I run the logistic model using `xtr/ytr` I get error in `if (is.null(np) | (np[2] <= 1)) stop("x should be a matrix with 2 or more columns")`:

> argument is of length zero

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, it was a typo. Change `n<-row(A)` to `n<-nrow(A)` and it should've worked. But after that, `A[,i:length(x[,i])]=x[,i]` produces other error, since the size of A is 10x6 while the `length(x[,i])` is 10. Probaby you wanted to do different thing here, than what is currently coded.

For the second error, the `xtr` should have a size of at least `n x 2`. Also, your data is not appropriate for binomial glm. Observations should be either 1 or 0.

Comment: first part works now, but I thought "xtr" already had the correct number of columns because of how i defined idx? I'm confused because my last column in the matrix is supposed to be my binomial data.

Comment: `xtr<-x[idx]` will give you a vector. Probably what you want is `xtr<-x[idx, ]`. Anyway, try to edit the code in the question, if you could, so we can get on the same page.

Comment: That worked, but now I have that observation error you mentioned. How do I change the glmnet formula so that it uses the last binomial column of my initial matrix? 

I tried: myglm<-glmnet(ytr,yts,family="multinomial"); 

because ytr/yts are binomial. I understand I need this to be n x 2, but I have no idea how to implement the logistic regression if I can't use this formula.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to open a new question while providing the data to be processed (`xtr`, `ytr`, `xts`, `yts`), codes you've tried, initial intention, and errors produced. Then the discussion can be focused more, and  there could be others that can answer it better.